# Can I assign the term "is eigenvector" and "is eigenmatrix" of matrix $P$ in my specific (infinite-size) case?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, matrix-theory, eigenvector

*Remark: I [asked this in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3459752/1714), the question got views and votes but seemingly no one had an answer so far.*

*Background: I'm rereading a couple of my exploratory (surely not research-level) math-essays and want to fix some possible wrong or misleading expressions. I've used the following notions/expressions a couple of years already but I would like to confirm that I can really use it in revisions of my web-essays.*

Consider the (upper triangular) infinite "Pascal"/"binomial"-matrix $P$ with top-left element as
$$\small \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 . & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
 . & . & 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 \\ 
 . & . & . & 1 & 4 & 10 \\ 
 . & . & . & . & 1 & 5 \\ 
 . & . & . & . & . & 1
 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Rightmultiplying it with the columnvector $E_1 = [1,1/1!,1/2!,1/3!, \dotsc]$ gives
$$  P \cdot E_1 = e \cdot E_1
$$
which has the form of an eigenvector equation as known from the cases with matrices of finite size. However, using $P$ and $E_1$ truncated to finite size $P^\star$ and $E_1^\star$ this would never be correct since $P^\star$ has no diagonalization.
Back to infinite size: in general with some columnvector $E(x)=[1, x^1, x^2/2!, x^3/3!, \dotsc]$ we have
$$  P \cdot E(x) = e^x \cdot E(x)
$$
thus for each $x$ we have that $P$ has $E(x)$ as eigenvector to eigenvalue $e^x$.

Now what I'm discussing in a couple of essays are a second type of infinite matrices, namely the concatenation of vectors $E_n=E(n)$ to a matrix $$EZ=[E_0,E_1,E_2,E_3,\dotsc]$$
and following the example I could write
$$ P \cdot EZ = EZ \cdot {^dV}(e) \\\qquad \qquad \qquad \text{ where ${^dV}(e) = \operatorname{diagonal}([1,e,e^2,e^3...])$}
$$
which has again the form of an eigenmatrix-decomposition (or "diagonalization").
I always tended to say, that

- "$EZ$ is an eigenmatrix of $P$" (or is matrix-of-eigenvectors), or that
- "$P$ of infinite size has a diagonalization"

and used this at several places in my manuscripts.

But because for the case of ***finite*** size $P^\star$ has ***no***  diagonalization (it has only a Jordan-form), I feel it might be too sloppy to formulate this as an Eigenmatrix-relation or even as "diagonalization of $P$" (the latter is even more problematic since the matrix $EZ$ has no inverse/reciprocal and we cannot write $P=EZ \cdot {^dV}(e) \cdot EZ^{-1}$).

> Q: How could I correctly express that relation, even in a informal context? Can I still apply the terms "matrix of eigenvectors", "… of eigenvalues"  and "diagonalization"?

---

***Update, added***. One argument which is possibly against the use of the concept of *diagonalization* here, is perhaps that of the existence of a Jordan-decomposition for the finite-size case $P^\star$. The top-left $6 \times 6$ -truncation of that (finite-size) Jordan-decomposition $P^\star = S^\star \cdot J^\star \cdot S^{\star -1}$
[image: picture1]
shows known matrices $S^\star$ (from Stirlingnumbers $1$st kind, left hand, factorially scaled) , the simple matrix $J^\star$ (in the middle) and $S^{\star-1}$  (from Stirlingnumbers $2$st kind, right hand, factorially scaled)
(or in a non-canonical rescaled version, but Stirlingnumbers nicer recognizable):
[image: picture2]
I don't know, whether it is more appropriate to apply the generalization to the case of infinite-size for the Jordan-decomposition, but if we do this, than we had a parallel between "diagonalization" and "Jordan-decomposition" which likely points to some incompatibility here with respect to the "diagonalization"-concept for the case of infinite size.

---

*P.s.: don't know the best tagging for MO. Please feel free and improve if you think fit.*

Comment: from the eigenvalue equation ${\rm det}\,(\lambda-P)=0$ the conclusion would be that all eigenvalues of $P$ are equal to 1 (not some power of $e$).

Comment: @CarloBeenakker - yes, that's a concurring observation. But because for the case of infinite matrix-size my observation is also true I need some reliable terminology for that.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker - I don't know whether the following is a meaningful remark here, but let's see. For the case of infinite size we can also have *multiple left-inverses* (even if the matrix is lower triangular). An example is the factorially scaled matrix of Stirlingnumbers second kind. Its ("principal") inverse for the case of infinite size is the factorially scaled matrix of Stirlingnumbers first kind. (As for instance described in the NIST - handbook) But there are also infinitely many other left-inverses possible, according to the multiplicy of $\exp(\log(1+x)+2k\pi i)$. Maybe it's related.

Comment: The definition of eigenvalues, eigenvector, and even 'eigenmatrix' don't rely on the space being finite dimensional. The only problem is that in the infinite dimensional case you have to make sure that your objects actually belong to the space. A meaningful space for your problem is $\ell^2$.

Comment: @lcv - thanks for your comment. I'm not sure I'll get the clause "if...belong to the same space". Because I want to become precise with this might you kindly extend your comment, possibly to an answer-box?

Comment: Can you link the MSE question? I can think about it after the weekend

Comment: @lcv - done. (link is at the introductional remark)

Comment: I would say that "eigenvector" and "eigenvalue" are totally natural terms in this context. "Eigenmatrix" I have never heard, sounds highly non-standard. "Diagonalization" typically means, also in infinite dimensional context, that one has found a *basis* of the space in question (in the appropriate sense, e. g. Hilbert basis) in which the operator acts diagonally. Since this is far from truth in your case, I would refrain from using this term.

Comment: I've never heard of the term ••eigenmatrix••, except in the context that something is acting on a space of matrices (so an eigenvector). I would not use that term, but eigenvector, eigenvalue, are OK in this general context.

Comment: @DavidHandelman - Thanks for your comment. Well, I know that "eigenmatrix" should be called "matrix of eigenvectors", but wrote it for shortness. But not that case of naming should be the problem here, but the use of/reference to the concept at all in this case of infinite matrices is my problem.

Comment: @Kostya_I - thanks for your comment too. The diagonally acting seems to me present as of my given example. But possibly I did not yet understand some further aspect (whether the matrix **EZ** is a *basis* or not in the appropriate space). Could you please say something more in this direction?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms, yes, my issue is with it being a basis. For me, to "diagonalize" an operator means to be able to compute it easily on any vector (by expanding the latter in the eigenbasis); in particular a diagonalization should somehow encompasses *all eigenvalues*. In your case, I am not sure what is even the appropriate space in which this operator acts and what one would mean by "all eigenvalues", but certainly $E(x)$ for $x\notin\mathbb{R}$ have every right right to be called so.

Comment: @Kostya_I - as a self-Iearner (widely) I have not yet a firm understanding of the problem with not having/being a basis in this case. I'll see what I can take from my sources this weekend. Something I came across already might be taken from the existence of the Jardan-decomposition of the ***P***-matrix, which is valid (and has constant entries) for every finite size of $P^\star$. In this view the existence of a basis seems to be easy to state. (With $P^\star= S^\star \cdot J \cdot S^{\star -1}$ we have $S^\star$ as truncation of the matrix of Stirlingnumbers) (...contd...).

Comment: (...contd...) From here it seems somehow natural to accept the existence of the Jordan-decomposition of the infinite size as generalization of the existence for the finite-size case. And then the talking of existence of a diagonalization *at the same case* would introduce some conceptual mixing and should be avoided for this reason alone. Hmmm. (I'll add this thought in the original question later today) *(p.s. "Jordan-decomposition " instead of "Jardan-..." in the previous comment, sorry)*

Comment: I guess there's no ambiguity that eigenvalue $t$ (for a linear endomorphism $A$ of a $K$-linear space $V$) means $A-t$ is non-injective (and eigenvector is defined in the obvious way). I've encountered "algebraic spectral value" to mean that $A-t$ is non-bijective, and topological spectral value to mean, when $A$ is continuous on some topological vector space, that $A-t$ is not (bijective with continuous inverse). Of course most results only carry over finite dimension only. Viewing $V$ as module over the PID $K[t]$ yields some useful information anyway in infinite dimension.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to call $E(x)=(1, x^1, x^2/2!, x^3/3!, \cdots)$ a *fixed point* of the linear map $E\mapsto M_\lambda\cdot E$, with $M_\lambda=\lambda P$ and *scale factor* $\lambda=e^{-x}$. In this way you can avoid the words *eigenvector* and *eigenvalue,* which mean something different in this context.

Comment: Ah, well, the formulation *"a fixed point of the linear map"* did not yet come to my mind. Thanks for that! But perhaps I should expand my question. Because in other cases of such infinite triangular matrices we have consecutive powers of a certain constant in the diagonal and might easier say, that "we have an eigensystem property": The idea from functional iteration which leads to the well known "Schroeder-function" can -via the connotation of the so-called "Carlemanmatrices"- be identified with the diagonalization in the cases of finite matrix size ...

Comment: ... where the matrix of eigenvectors (and its inverse) in the infinite case are associated to that Schroeder-functions. I've read such expressions elsewhere, for instance in R.Aldrovandi's articles on iterated exponeniation/Tetration. (But I think also elsewhere). From this I think, -if the use of the terms from diagonalization are not appropriate for my given case- then it would be good for the reader, ***why** in this case we can **not** apply that termini* but must resort to something else. - hmm. Sorry if I'm just confusing things more than explicate...